# Change port number in httpd.conf

Tags: php, apache

I wanted to change my port from 80 to some other number as I could not install/start Apache. I know that the changes need to be done in the httpd.conf. So i found the line:

```
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen [::0]:80
```

How do I change this part to a new port number? Will the following be efficient?

```
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:81
Listen 0.0.0.0:81
Listen [::0]:81
```

Comment: Try `service httpd restart` too

Comment: No I didn't as I'm not sure if that's how it has to be done.

Comment: Try it first then ask if it doesn't work. This sort of question doesn't belong on this site btw

Comment: @BeeCoding: Do I need to change the following to 81 as well?
#
ServerName localhost:80.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not "root", you cannot bind to ports below 1024... presuming the situation isn't just that port 80 is already in use, this seems like the next-most-likely candidate.

Note that you will also likely need to change any  or similar blocks to refer to the new port.

You generally don't need (or want, because it's confusing) to specify a port number in "ServerName" and "ServerAlias" lines. So if you have any there, I'd remove them and leave just the actual domain name(s).

Answer (score 0):

**This is what i have**

```
#Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 

#prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.

#Listen 12.34.56.78:8080

Listen 8080
```

There's your answer!!!!

**This is what you have**

```
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.

#Listen 12.34.56.78:81

Listen 0.0.0.0:81

Listen [::0]:81 <- REMOVE THIS
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my fix for localhost not working (going to.com)
wampserver3.0.6_x64_apache2.4.23_mysql5.7.14_php5.6.25-7.0.10

make a copy first of
C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\conf\httpd.conf

Look for Listen 12.

then edit original
httpd.conf in text editor (notepad)

Lines 70 or so:

```
71      #Listen 12.34.56.78:80
72      Listen 0.0.0.0:80
73      Listen [::0]:80
```

Replace with

```
    #Listen 12.34.56.78:80
    #Listen 0.0.0.0:80      commented out for below
    Listen 8080
    #Listen [::0]:80        commented out for below
    Listen [::0]:8080
```

Save... Restart Wampserver

Answer (score -1):

By default, Apache server listens to port 80. However, in some cases the port 80 is used by other programs such as Skype. In that case you need to change your port number. So, look out for httpd.conf file which is placed inside of conf directory in Apache installation directory (therefore you are on right path). Then just change the port number, save your changes and restart your service.